# Firefox bootstrap grid displacement issue

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem showing my page visually the same on FireFox and Chrome.

Page renders correctly with Chrome (showing icons in two lines), but in Firefox icons break visually and create a third row. I think that the problem is with Bootstrap, but I don't understand why. I have tried different solutions, but nothing.

The page with this problem: 
[image]
Link of the page: http://www.unishare.it/sedi/1

Comment: I don't see any differences on both browsers for that page. Can you provide more information about what your problem is? I see that there is a problem but cannot understand what...

Comment: ?? On Firefox we have three rows,while on Chrome two rows. The correct behavior should be the second (Chrome).

Comment: I editted your question in order to make it understandable. I had to delete the picture link, because that was the thing that made me confused in the first place. If the meaining of your question is changed, let me know.

Comment: Yes,you have centered the problem.

Comment: I think I accidently deleted the page link instead of the image... Can you please edit your question replacing the link with your page? I want to have another look at your code.

Comment: I have edited the post with the link.

Comment: And I have editted my answer. Take a look ;)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I know the rules but the code is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of things going on in your HTML. Firstly, you shouldn't write any code outside of the  scope. You should place your custom style elements always inside of the  tag. Secondly, move bootstrap.css to the top. That is your css boilerplate (That is the css code that resets your visual settings across all browsers). All the other css files (font-awesome.css, slider.css, etc...) should be placed after the boilerplate css code/file.

After placing all library css files, your custom css files should be the last ones in the  tag (I mean all the style codes at the top of your html page).

Try these suggestions and come back with the result. I believe you'll be good to go then.

EDIT: After taking a second look and playing your HTML with FireFox's dev tools, I created a solution for you. Just surround your "portfolio-boxes" divs with a row. They are not actually recognized as a seperate row in your DOM, that's why they don't appear in two seperate lines.

In short, you should create a div with a class of "row" for every "portfolio-boxes" div, seperately.

Does that solve your problem? If yes, you can vote up and select the answer ;)

Comment: I understand your point of view,but bootstrap.css is already on the top. it's in a php file that manage the header part of the page. Also the font-awesome.cc,slider.css are already there.

Comment: Oh yes! You are my saviour! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't. I have no enough reputation. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should have upvoted your question. Now you do have enough rep.

Comment: No. I have reputation level 12. The minimum is 15

Comment: Wait a little, rep calculation takes some time. You'll be like 27 after my upvotes for your comments and question. I hope to see you helping other's problems one day ;)

Comment: Ok,I wait it. I hope so!